# SetMaxResults() not working as expected in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am a beginner in Hibernate and getting some errors using the `SetMaxResults()` function. This is my MySQL table data:

```
1   J. C. Smell
2   J. C. Smell
3   J. C. Smell
4   J. C. Smell
```

This is the method to retrieve one record from 4 identical records:

```
private Person findPerson(Session session, String name){
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Person p where p.name=:name");
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        Person person = (Person)query.list();
        if(person == null)
            return null;
        return person;
    }
```

I expect to get one record, but according to the Exception am getting an ArrayList of records. The exception comes from this line
`Person person = (Person)query.list();` That line has the number `34` in my source code. This is the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to chapter3.simple.Person
    at chapter3.simple.RankingTest.findPerson(RankingTest.java:34)
    at chapter3.simple.RankingTest.savePerson(RankingTest.java:41)
    at chapter3.simple.RankingTest.testSaveRanking(RankingTest.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    ...
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Is the setMaxResults(1) not supposed to return 1 results from the records?

Answer (score 3):

```
 Person person = (Person)query.list();
```

That is an illegal cast. Though the list have a single element, you cannot magically cast a list to `Person`. When you set max result, it still returns a list with 1 element.

Hence you have to do

```
Person person = (Person)query.list().get(0);
```

Comment: Hi, Is the setMaxResults(1)  not suppose to return 1 results from the records?

Comment: It is an error-prone, of course `Person person = (Person)query.list().get(0);`

Comment: @EddyFreeman Yes it is. It returning only one element, which is inside the list. not a direct person :)

Comment: @v.ladynev Please feel free to edit the post, if there any improvements to the answer.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ A query can return an empty list :)

Comment: @v.ladynev Hope OP checks for the size of list :)

Answer (score 1):

Better use

```
Person person = (Person)query.uniqueResult();
```

But be careful with this, it throws exception if there is not unique entry.

But it your case use

```
Person person = (Person)query.list().get(0);
```

Comment: It is not suitable, because of an exception, when there is not a result records.

Comment: It is an error-prone, of course `Person person = (Person)query.list().get(0);`

Comment: @v.ladynev That's not a good practice to get non-unique entry by unknown order, so I think topic starter should use stricter criteria to get unique result

Comment: @v.ladynev some time it's better to catch exception that spend lot time to find duplicates in database

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code like this, i hope it will work. Thanks

```
private Person findPerson(Session session, String name){
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Person p where p.name=:name")
        query.setParameter("name", name)
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        return (Person)query.uniqueResult();
}
```